# Airodump-ng stops working after de-authentication with aireplay-ng

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm trying to de-authenticate a client while airodump is collecting the packets but after I type:

> sudo aireplay-ng -0 1 -a AP_MAC -c CLIENT_MAC mon0

in the airodump screen I get:

> read failed: Network is down
>   Interface mon0:
>   ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device
>   Can't reopen mon0

I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Usually it happens for exactly the reason stated in the error message: there is no interface "mon0", because you didn't put your wireless adapter into monitor mode.

Comment: airmon-ng start wlan0